# Pre-90s anime movie, girl on a journey to find her brother encounters a dragon/dinosaur-shaped patrol vehicle

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I'm trying to find the title of an anime I saw when I was really young. Most likely pre-90's but definitely before 1995. I only vaguely remember some details. It follows a girl who journeys to find her brother. Her brother works for the villain, or has been corrupted by him or something (like a Vader/Palpatine thing).

There's like a city or fortress she travels to looking for him. She has some companions, but I don't remember any details about them or her appearance. I remember one particular scene where they're in the city/fortress, the sky is dark and I don't think the city/fortress was manned. They hear a noise and they duck and hide and then some kind of rolling patrol vehicle/robot (like it drove on wheels, not the whole thing rolled) whips around a corner and zooms by. Here's the weird thing that I'm not sure I remember correctly, I'm pretty sure the vehicle/robot was like dragon- or dinosaur-shaped.

Eventually they encounter the brother. The only thing I maybe remember about him was that he wore like a dark cloak or cape. Possibly a hat or mask.

I think the brother ends up betraying the villain and saving his sister from him.

Answer (score 5):

This really reminds me of *Unico in The Island of Magic*. Great, scary children’s anime from 1983. It has the girl searching for her brother who works for the villain (who is very creepy) and it had a wheeled dragon.

[image: Blonde guy wearing a blue cape with insect-like horns holding his scratched shoulder, blonde little girl screaming in the background]

[image: pale villain with big eyes and a triangular-shaped face saying "please don't speak of such things"]

[image: dinosaur-shaped robot, yellow body, red paws]

Comment: I'm the OP. Unico in the Island of Magic is it. I've looked for this for years. Gonna go watch it asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be *Escaflowne*. There is a series and a movie based on the same story.

Just somethings are different from the memory. A girl and a boy (teens) are looking for a diamond to use some mechas, the diamonds are the mechas' energy,  and the diamonds are from the hearts of dragons.  The evil brother is the boy's brother. The girl comes from Earth,  and she has a power to see the future or feel predictions. The brother was on the evil side but became good at the end or something like that,  like betraying the main evil boss.

The only thing is that they were released after 1995. Series in 1996 and movie on 2000.

[image: main characters: brown-haired girl wearing a skirt and black-haired young boy, several characters in the background and a dark green mecha]

[image: evil brother, blue spiky hair, dark cloak, his right hand looks like a robot prosthesis]